# Tweepy Stream Error "Stream encountered HTTP error: 403",

Tags: python, tweepy

i have elevated access and turned on OAuth 1.0a, therefore i have access to the Twitter API v1.1. I try to stream specific keywords, however i always get the error "Stream encountered HTTP error: 403". Can anyone help?

```
import tweepy

apikey = "x"
apikeysecret = "x"
accesstoken = "x"
accesstokensecret = "x"
bearertoken = "x"

auth = tweepy.OAuth1UserHandler(apikey, apikeysecret, accesstoken, accesstokensecret)
api = tweepy.API(auth,wait_on_rate_limit=True)

class MyStreamListener(tweepy.Stream):
    def on_status(self, status):
        print(status.user.screen_name + ": " +status.text)

myStream = MyStreamListener(apikey,apikeysecret,accesstoken,accesstokensecret)
myStream.filter(track=["solana"])
```

Comment: Are you using a Twitter Developer App created on or after 2022-04-29?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try adding `auth.secure = True`

This is what your code would look like:

```
import tweepy

apikey = "x"
apikeysecret = "x"
accesstoken = "x"
accesstokensecret = "x"
bearertoken = "x"

auth = tweepy.OAuth1UserHandler(apikey, apikeysecret, accesstoken, accesstokensecret)
auth.secure = True
api = tweepy.API(auth,wait_on_rate_limit=True)

class MyStreamListener(tweepy.Stream):
    def on_status(self, status):
        print(status.user.screen_name + ": " +status.text)

myStream = MyStreamListener(apikey,apikeysecret,accesstoken,accesstokensecret)
myStream.filter(track=["solana"])
```